# Linker can't find libcrypto

Tags: gcc, libcrypto

I am getting a linker error with:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives me 
/usr/lib

In /usr/lib there is a 
libcrypto.so.1.0.0

And in my gcc line in the Makefile I have a -lcrypto flag added.

I am not sure how I can fix this problem.

Comment: What OS/Distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu13.10

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. Or have you already installed that?

Comment: Installing that package did it. I'm not sure, what it changed. It should still be looking for libcrypto.so in my /usr/lib, right?

Comment: Yes, it searches for `libcrypto.so`, but you only had `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, which is an indicator that some dev-package is missing.

Comment: Ah. Yes, sorry for the duplicate.